# What are the limitations for table id in slony?

Tags: postgresql, slony

I'm setting up postgres replication with slony. I have many schemas containing the same (or very similar) set of tables, so I create separate replications sets for every schema. Each schema has specific unique number, so this number becomes id of the set.

Then I add tables to replication. As far as I know every table has to have unique id across all tables. Because tables are created every month, the id for the table is concatenated from year, month and set id. Everything works fine, but when set id has four digits (so table id will be for example: `2015051162`), it gives me an error after adding table to replication:

```
 2015-05-29 10:09:20 CEST INFO   remoteWorkerThread_1: syncing set 101162 with 1 table(s) from provider 1
 2015-05-29 10:09:22 CEST CONFIG slon: child terminated signal: 11; pid: 18738, current worker pid: 18738
 2015-05-29 10:09:22 CEST CONFIG slon: restart of worker in 10 seconds
```

It seems to me that this table id is too big, because for sets with single-digit ids everything replicates correctly. Are there any limitations for table id, except that it has to be unique in the replication cluster?

Comment: this seems like an error during replication; did you get any other errors, does slony accept the configuration when you load it?

Comment: I didn't get any errors, I searched through log. Slony accepts creating set, adding table to set and subscribing this set.

Comment: yeah, I read the docs later (see my answer), this behaviour would fit

Answer (score 1):

**Are there limitations?**

There's no hard limit, except that it should be an `int`.

**But why does it fail?**

As it appears, using high IDs does use up some memory, due to the way those IDs are stored. As per the [fine documentation](http://www.slony.info/documentation/2.0/stmtsetaddtable.html):

> Note that Slony-I generates an in-memory array indicating all of the fully qualified table names; if you use large table ID numbers, the sparsely-utilized array can lead to substantial wastage of memory. Each potential table ID consumes a pointer to a char, commonly costing 4 bytes per table ID on 32 bit architectures, and 8 bytes per table ID on 64 bit architectures.

That means, if you generate a set of IDs with a biggest ID of, say, 5000 for 100 tables, slony *would* (try to) create an array which would be able to hold 5000 table entries. Only, that 4900 entries would be unused.

For an ID of `2015051162` you'd have to reserve space of 4 bytes (in 32 bit) * 2015051162 = about 8GB for this array, so the segfault is probably just about an unfilled request to the OS for that memory.

Comment: I read this note in slony's documentation but I thought that "wastage of memory" doesn't lead to segfault, just replication would use more resources than actually needed. For now I resolved the problem by generating random id from wide range of values, which should be sufficient, because there will be no more than 5000 tables replicated at once.

Comment: try to keep your biggest ID as low as possible, see my edit about an ID of 5000 for 100 tables.

Comment: ok, it's see now why it can cause a problem. So the best solution would be to iterate through values of `tab_id` in `_cluster._sl_table` and select first unused id?

Comment: this *might* work. I'm always a bit hesitant relying on undocumented values / ones that start wirth "_" (python coder here). since you seem to implement you own replication scheme on top of slony, you could also keep track of your own data, do a `CREATE SEQUENCE ...` and use that.